# DefinitionInvalidException from Microsoft Report Viewer 2008

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, reportviewer

My app (winforms .net 2.0 / vs2008) works fine on my dev machine but on one of test machines i'm getting this exception.
Has anybody encountered something similar?

```
************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. See the report server log files for more information.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.DataProtectionLocal.ProtectData(Byte[] data, Int32 dwFlags)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataSourceInfo..ctor(String originalName, String extension, String connectionString, Boolean originalConnectStringExpressionBased, Boolean integratedSecurity, String prompt)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.ReadDataSource(DataSourceNameValidator dataSourceNames, PublishingContext context)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.ReadDataSources(PublishingContext context)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.ReadReport()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.Phase1(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] definition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, String& description, String& language, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] definition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.get_Snapshot()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext context, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.CompileReport()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at XXX.Helpers.Report.PrintFavs(List`1 list, String header, String filename) in C:\Data\projects\workdir_cpv\Src\Classes\Helpers\Report.cs:line 112
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vs2008 designer for reports and report viewer are not backwards compatible with 2.0. In the same way you cannot design 2005 reports with vs2008 - that may be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar once. You might want to make sure the test machine has the ReportViewer dll installed in the GAC. Microsoft has created an [installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=CC96C246-61E5-4D9E-BB5F-416D75A1B9EF&displaylang=en) to make this easier.

Question: Are you using Reporting Services in local mode with a report viewer control inside winforms?

Comment: No, I'm not using report viewer control because it doesn't have translation to my clients' language.
i'm printing directly to file using solution from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My installer copies all required dlls

Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll

Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll

Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll

to ProgramFiles/myAppname folder.

It works perfectly on Vista/XP but the issue is at Win98.
I'll try to install these dll's at GAC, maybe that's a problem. I'm trying to avoid running extra installers inside my installer.

@keithwarren7:

if that's true, then it's really stupid. do you know any simple & free report engine for .net 2.0?

Comment: The problem is that the RDL spec between 2005 and 2008 changed and the Tablix was introduced. It may be possible but I have not had any luck.